Golang, designing a flexible attribute system with diverse possible value types
So long story short, I am trying to model an attribute system for my application. It would have user attributes and system attributes, that behave exactly the same except one being tied to a specific user.
Think of things like:

key: onboarding.completed, user_id: x <- a bool that is tied to a user
key: featurex.enabled <- bool indicating whether a featurex is enabled app wide
key: user.preferences, user_id: y <- json containing users selected preferences

The structure of the table is:
create table attributes (
    id uuid primary key default gen_random_uuid(),
    attribute_key text not null,
    user_id uuid references users (id),
    value text not null, -- can be a json, a string, a bool, float, int
    created_at timestamptz not null default now(),
    updated_at timestamptz not null default now(),
    unique (user_id, attribute_key)
);

I had several iterations on how to model this, and settled on something like this.
I modeled the attribute using interface{}, and a trust in me that I will indeed do the right thing and provide adequate types.
type Key string

const (
    SubscriptionDiscountKey Key = "subscription_discount"
    ProPlanPropertiesKey    Key = "pro_plan_properties"
    BasicPlanPropertiesKey  Key = "basic_plan_properties"
)

type Attribute struct {
    Key       Key
    UserID    uuid.UUID
    Value     interface{} // can be a map[string]interface{}, int, string, bool, float32
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    CreatedAt time.Time
}

// MustValue will get the value out of a Attribute. If the value can't be unmarshalled into the provided type, it will panic.
func MustValue[T any](a Attribute) T { // <- annoying that I cannot put func (a Attribute) MustValue[T any]() T {}
    marshalled, err := json.Marshal(a.Value)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    dst := new(T)

    if err := json.Unmarshal(marshalled, dst); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return *dst
}

type SubscriptionDiscountUserAttr struct {
    Value     float32   `json:"value"`
    Type      string    `json:"type"`
    ExpiresAt time.Time `json:"expires_at,omitempty"`
}

func (s SubscriptionDiscountUserAttr) Validate() error {...}

type PlanPropertiesAttr struct {
    Price                  map[string]float32 `json:"price"`
    TrialPeriodDays        int                `json:"trial_period_days"`
}

Getting the attribute
func (a activities) Get(ctx context.Context, params domain.GetActivityParams) (domain.GetActivityResult, error) {
    if ve := params.Validate(); ve != nil {
        return domain.GetActivityResult{}, common.InvalidParams(ve)
    }

    attr, err := a.store.Find(ctx, store.FindParams{
        AttributeKey: string(params.Key),
        UserID: uuid.NullUUID{
            UUID:  params.UserID,
            Valid: params.UserID != uuid.Nil,
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        return domain.GetActivityResult{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to find, %w", err)
    }

    var value interface{}
    if err := parseValue(attr.Value, &value); err != nil {
        return domain.GetActivityResult{}, fmt.Errorf("failed to parse value, %w", err)
    }

    return domain.GetActivityResult{
        Data: domain.Attribute{
            Key:       domain.Key(attr.AttributeKey),
            UserID:    attr.UserID.UUID,
            Value:     value,
            UpdatedAt: attr.UpdatedAt,
            CreatedAt: attr.CreatedAt,
        },
    }, nil
}

func parseValue(rawValue string, value *interface{}) error {
    // Check if the value is JSON
    if strings.HasPrefix(rawValue, "{") || strings.HasPrefix(rawValue, "[") {
        if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(rawValue), value); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal JSON, %w", err)
        }
        return nil
    }

    // Check if the value is an int
    if intVal, err := strconv.Atoi(rawValue); err == nil {
        *value = intVal
        return nil
    }

    // Check if the value is a float
    if floatVal, err := strconv.ParseFloat(rawValue, 64); err == nil {
        *value = floatVal
        return nil
    }

    // Check if the value is a boolean
    if boolVal, err := strconv.ParseBool(rawValue); err == nil {
        *value = boolVal
        return nil
    }

    // Default to string
    *value = rawValue
    return nil
}

Several notes here

I intentionally panic because incorrectly mapping the type of the attribute in code is programmers mistake and its correct to assert it as a system failure/ bug
I think the code is in okay state but I can't shake off the feeling I am either misusing the golang type system (and I probably am since this kind of guess work on the types is not idiomatic)
Generics don't help nearly as much as I am used to from other languages

The biggest hurdle is I have no idea how to test this thing, since I cannot store types inside my test cases
    cases := []struct {
        Key           domain.Key
        UserID        uuid.UUID
        Type          interface{}// <- incorrect and does not work
        ExpectedValue interface{}
    }{
        {
            UserID: userID,
            Key:    domain.SubscriptionDiscountKey,
            Type:   domain.SubscriptionDiscountUserAttr{},
            ExpectedValue: domain.SubscriptionDiscountUserAttr{},
        },
        {
            Key:  domain.BasicPlanPropertiesKey,
            Type: domain.PlanPropertiesAttr{},
            ExpectedValue: domain.PlanPropertiesAttr{},
        },
    }

    for _, c := range cases {
        t.Run(string(c.Key), func(t *testing.T) {
            res, err := act.Get(context.Background(), domain.GetActivityParams{
                Key:    c.Key,
                UserID: c.UserID,
            })
            require.NoError(t, err)

            // Validate the result
            val, err := domain.MustValue[reflect.V(c.Type)](res.Data)  <- not sure how to do this
            require.NoError(t, err)

            require.Equal(t, c.ExpectedValue, val)
        })
    }

Any ideas, articles, resources, tips are greatly appreciated. It's a very core system that will be used throughout the app so I really want to get the DX and the design of it correct.
